# Invite person from contacts who doesn't have app?

Tags: ios, deep-linking

I want to let users of my iPhone app invite people from their contacts to a group they're creating. I can use deeplinks for people that already have the app installed to have an invitation automatically show up, but I was wondering if I can somehow pass custom information to someone downloading the app for the first time so after they initially open the app they'll have an invite waiting.

As far as I can tell this is impossible but I was wondering if there's any other way to somehow associate a contact with that person making an account on their own device. My application uses gmail authentication for account creation so if everybody had each other's gmails saved in their contact this might be possible, but that's not the case unfortunately. If I could get a user's phone number then it would be easy but I know that's not allowed without specifically asking the user.

Does anybody know if it's possible to do something like deeplinking for people installing the app for the first time?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Google Firebase Dynamic Links. Google has a guide for this here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/

Comment: I'm using Firebase for my app and want to use Dynamic Links but can't figure out how I'd send a dynamic url that would automatically add an invite to the receiver once they make an account. From what I understand Dynamic Links are for once the user has already downloaded the app.

Comment: @MarksCode When the app is opened for the very first time, the app can check if the user clicked a dynamic link. If they did, your app can get information passed through the link. Check out this video: https://youtu.be/sFPo296OQqk

Comment: At about 12:25 in the video, you can see the process for handling a dynamic link when the app is opened for the first time after being installed.

Comment: I think Firebase Dynamic Links is an unsupported library. This line in their documentation: `let components = FIRDynamicLinkComponents(link: link, domain: domain)` gives me `Use of unresolved identifier 'FIRDynamicLinkComponents'`

Comment: Did you add the Dynamic Links cocoapod to your project?

Comment: Yep... I don't this library is maintained anymore.

Comment: I'm using it in two apps right now and it's working great. I don't see any signs of it not being maintained.

Comment: So does this line work for you? `let components = FIRDynamicLinkComponents(link: link, domain: domain)`?

Comment: You're using that trying to create a dynamic link? I don't remember seeing this "iOS Builder API" for generating links. I see that Google's page on creating dynamic links was modified  two days ago, so maybe this is new. I'm not using `FIRDynamicLinkComponents` and instead I'm using Google's REST API to create dynamic links.

Comment: Ah, do you have the link to get started with Google's api? I'd expect Firebase's to be working since they're a Google company..

Comment: You can create a long link manually by using [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually) or you can use [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest) which shows you how to use the REST API to create links or shorten a long link.

Comment: Firebase Dynamic Links is absolutely still supported and under active development. If you're getting a `FIRDynamicLinkComponents` error, you have a configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, here is what I'd do:

**Scenario:** Send Invite

- If the email invited by a user is a registered email, done.
- If the email invited by user is not a registered email, store it in a separate table (`pending invites`)

**Scenario:** Sign up/ Sign in

- User registers using email, store user information.
- When the user logs in, check if email exists in `pending invites` table, if exists, present invitation.
- Delete user from `pending invites` table

Not sure if you have it already but you might need a db table to keep the invitations sent by your users.

Comment: I have all the resources to accomplish this except for one key problem: People don't store each other's gmails in their contacts much so this solution would miss a lot of times.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is called **Deferred Deep Linking** (`Deep Linking` refers to using a link to open your app  directly to a specific piece of content, and `Deferred` means that it works even if the app isn't installed first).

As you noted, there's no native way to accomplish this on either iOS or Android. URL schemes don't work, because they *always* fail with an error if the app isn't installed. Apple's newer [Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html) in iOS 9+ get closer in that they at least don't trigger an *error* if the app isn't installed, but you'd still have to handle redirecting the user from your website to the App Store. You can't pass context through to the app after install with Universal Links, so you wouldn't be able to present the invitation. Additionally. Universal Links actually aren't supported [in a lot of places](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/universal-app-links/support/ios/#appsbrowsers-that-support-universal-links).

To make this work, you need a remote server to close the loop. You can [build this yourself](https://blog.branch.io/how-to-build-a-linking-solution-for-every-device), but you really shouldn't for a lot of reasons (not the least of which being you have more important things to do). Free services like [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: Branch is so awesome I work there) and Firebase Dynamic Links are designed to solve exactly this requirement, and can handle all of the backend infrastructure for deferred deep linking so you don't have to. **From your perspective, as the developer, you'll seamlessly get exactly the same data to work with whether or not the app was installed when the link was clicked.**